# How to print table headers on each page for a Material UI data grid table without overlapping with the rows on 2nd page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, material-ui, datagrid

I have been trying to print table headers on each page but the problem is I am using Material UI grid to create the table and it does not support by default property of table(thead) to print the headers on each page.

[Header overlapping with rows on 2nd page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFJdZ.png)

I have searched a lot and tried bunch of solutions like making headers position fixed
`'.MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders': { display: 'table-header-group !important', position: 'fixed !important', top: '0 !important'},`

adding `break-inside: avoid;` into table rows but it does not solve the overlapping problem.

I have even tried disabling iframe in the @media print but nothing helped.

Can someone please help me solving this frustrating issue. Its been 2 days I am trying to find a work around

Here is sandbox link to play around :- (Click on EXPORT button on top right side to see PRINT option) https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sn9r1c-m6jffn?file=demo.tsx